# Ag-Grid - Dynamically edit pinned row

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a button that manually adds a new row to top of table, and automatically enters edit mode on that new row. I recently updated the new to be a pinned row in order for it to display when filtered. However, I don't know I would access that pinned row to start editing.

Here is what I had before when the new row wasn't pinned:

```
gridOptionsApi.setFocusedCell(currentEmptyRowIndex || 0, "drawing_name");
gridOptionsApi.startEditingCell({
   rowIndex: currentEmptyRowIndex || 0,
   colKey: "drawing_name"
});
```

When I do this the first un-pinned row is toggled to edit mode instead of the first pinned row. **How would I specify the pinned row index for the `startEditingCell` function**?

Answer (score 0):

```
gridOptionsApi.setFocusedCell(currentEmptyRowIndex || 0, "drawing_name");
gridOptionsApi.startEditingCell({
   rowIndex: currentEmptyRowIndex || 0,
   colKey: "drawing_name",
   rowPinned: 'top',
});
```

rowPinned can be 'top' or 'bottom'